# How can I combine two images into one image object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I combine two images?

I mean I have two images: one small and another big one. I want to add small image onto big one at a specific point and I need to get an `UIImage` as the result.

I have tried `CGCreateImageFromMask` but that makes small image to cover bigger image completely.

Comment: Have a look at this question [stitch-picture-in-iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218388/stitch-picture-in-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` to generate a `CGContextRef`, then use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to get a reference to it.

Now draw your current images into the context. When you're done, use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()` to generate an `UIImage` from that context, and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to clean up.

See [Apple's UIKit Function Reference doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/UIKitFunctionReference.pdf).