# iOS image sizes for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have developed an small iOS app, where i have `image` named **bg.png** which is of dimension

> 1024 * 768 for iPad.

Now i have many images which has been created for `iPad` size. Now i need to make support of this app in iPhone, for that weather i need to create same set of images agian for `iPhone` size,

> 568 * 300 for iPhone.

or there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Scaling down the iPad image assets will destroy UX on iPhone. Also images like icon, splash screen usually contain company logo. Scaling down will tamper the look of the logo and overall image. Better way is to create separate images for iPhone form factor. Trim the png files using http://tinypng.org/ to keep binary size low.

Cheers!
Amar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to re-size the image by following code,

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(568, 300);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[yourIpadImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
newIphoneImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   + (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
        UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;
    }
```

You have option to change the Size of Your Image

Answer (score 0):

sathiamoorthys solution is a difficult way or rescaling your image. You can do that by simply creating a UIImageView, initialize it with a UIImage and then change its frame.
Note that your image will look scaled/distorted that way.

Answer (score 0):

follow this:

1. open the image in preview.
2. go to tools > adjust size
3. put in whatever size you want.
4. save the image as a different name.

Answer (score 0):

yes
you should create duplicate and resize them for iphone. Using same images for iphone will bring memory issues because the images are unnecessarily big for iphone.

Use any software to resize them or you can do this using `preview` also as [Nikita described above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562734/362310)

If you are doing this to create universal app then you must postfix `~ipad` in the name of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877362/create-uiimage-of-a-specific-size), May help you and solve your issue.

There is the some tips like:

1. Propotional scale,
2. Resize

Answer (score -1):

If you want your images to show up unscaled, you are going to need an additional image with the correct size.
So supporting both iPad with and without retina screens would require one image of 768x1024 and one of 1536 x 2048. For iPhone 3.5" you would need 960 x 640 when it is a retina screen or 480 x 320 when it is non-retina. For iPhone 5 (4" screen) you would need 568 x 320.
If you use UIImages method imageNamed: there is help from Apple. It loads on retina devices that method looks for the the image you specified with the postfix '@2x'. So you can simply code:
`UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage"]`
If you make sure you project contains myImage.png for non-retina devices and myImage@2x.png for retina devices the right image gets loaded at runtime.

Comment: Why the down vote? Is this answer in someway incorrect? Does it not address the OP's question? Was it by accident. My first try at helping someone outside of Apples devforums and I immediately receive minus points without explanation.